# I want to code a monte carlo simulation to find the optimal batch size m for a given probability p

Tags: python, montecarlo

I have a total number of samples which is equal to 10^6, but I do not want to test all of these samples, rather I want to determine an optimal batch size m using the monte carlo simulation for a given probability value. The probability values are between 10^-1 and 10^-4. The way to test the optimal batch size is as follows:
If m tests negative (no one has covid), this gives the result for all m individuals in the batch.
If m tests positive (someone has covid), all samples in the batch need to be tested, to find out who is infected

```
import numpy as np

def simulate_batch_testing(N, p, k):
    infected = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=N, p=[1-p, p])
    
    # Mix k samples in a batch
    mixed_sample = np.sum(np.random.choice(infected, size=k))
    
    if mixed_sample == 0:
        # If mixed sample tests negative, all individuals in the batch are clear
        return k
    else:
        # If mixed sample tests positive, retest all individuals in the batch
        return N

def monte_carlo_simulation(N, p, num_simulations):
    results = []
    
    for k in range(1, N + 1):
        total_tests = 0
        for _ in range(num_simulations):
            total_tests += simulate_batch_testing(N, p, k)
        avg_tests = total_tests / num_simulations
        results.append((k, avg_tests))
    
    return results

# Parameters
N = 10**6  # Number of samples
num_simulations = 1000  # Number of Monte Carlo simulations

# Probability values
p_values = [10**-1, 10**-2, 10**-3, 10**-4]

# Perform simulations for different p values
for p in p_values:
    simulation_results = monte_carlo_simulation(N, p, num_simulations)
    min_avg_tests = min(simulation_results, key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    print(f"For p = {p}, optimal batch size k is {min_avg_tests[0]} with an average of {min_avg_tests[1]:.2f} tests.")
```

I am not sure about the implementation of this code as it never seems to terminate and I am also not sure about the monte carlo simulation

Comment: You realize your are running `len(p_values) * N * num_simulations` or 4*10**9 simulations.  And even though each simulation runs in 0.0126 seconds, 4 billion of those will take over 50 million seconds, or over 584 days.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for pointing that out. What I thought is that you should run at least 1000 simulations to get a good approximation for the Monte Carlo simulation. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to reduce your number of simulations and/or parallelize across a large number of processors, and/or speed up each simulation.  For example, do you really need to do every `k`?  Perhaps reducing simulate_batch_testing to a one liner might improve performance.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "reducing simulate_batch_testing to a one liner"

Comment: I was thinking of eliminating the temporary `infected` variable by just in setting it into the `mixed_sample` calculation, and moving the `if mixed_sample == 0` block out of the function by changing the line to `total_tests += simulate_batch_testing(N , p, k) or k`, but that has almost no impact on the total time.  However, I think you get the equivalent statistics if you just assume that your random selection from the pool is just the first `k` members, so you can reduce that to a single `np.choice` call.

Comment: I also think you are counting wrong.  If your k-sized batch has 0 positive, then you need only the 1 test, not k tests, right?  And if the k sized batch has any positives then you need to do k individual tests to get the actual probability estimate which with the initial batch test means k+1 tests not N, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I believe that that function as a whole does not seem to work because if I set N to 1000 and the number of simulations to 100 and choose only one specific p-value, I get an output where the optimal batch size is equal to 1, and this cannot be right. Do you know what the issue could be here?

Comment: Sorry.  I was forgetting what your actual use case was there.  You are wanting to test all of the samples.  So you do want to generate a random N length array of infected, but you don't want to randomly sample those you want to simulate splitting them into k-length batches and see how often on average you need to go back and test all of the batch members. Hmm.

Comment: That truly better be done in C++/C/Rust/Fortran. Speed gain would be likely about 2 orders of magnitude

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments the primary problem here is that as written the `simulate_batch_testing` function is going to get called `len(p_values) * N * num_simulations` times, which with the given parameters comes to 4e+09.  So even though `simulate_batch_testing` runs in roughly 0.0126 seconds, the overall running time will be over a year and a half.

Unfortunately the `simulate_batch_testing` function also isn't quite simulating the batch testing correctly.  As written it takes one random `k` sized sample out of the population `N` and then acts like all of the `k` sized samples will require the same retesting or not.

To properly simulate batching the `N` samples into `k` sized samples you want something more like

```
def simulate_batch_testing(N, p, k):
    # create the total population
    population = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=N, p=[1-p, p])
    n_tests = 0
    # check each k sized batch
    for j in range(0, N, k):
        n_tests += 1
        if population[j:j+k].sum() > 0:
            n_tests += k
    return n_tests
```

which actually ends up being even two times slower than the original version.

I was able to get that back down to around the original time by writing it as

```
def simulate_batch_testing(N, p, k):
    # pad the population out to an even multiple of k with uninfected people
    padding = N % k
    N_padded = N + padding
    n_batches = N_padded // k
    population = np.pad(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=N, p=[1-p, p]), (0, padding))
    # use reshape to group into the batches
    groups = population.reshape(n_batches, k)
    # identify the groups that need retests
    retests = groups.any(axis=1)
    # calculate and return the total number of tests required
    return n_batches + retests.sum() * k
```

Perhaps some Numpy guru can provide some further optimization, but this is the best I have so far, and this still leaves a total simulation that will take way too long.  So, I would suggest reducing the `num_simulations` to 100, and limiting `k` to only go up to `N // 2` as it doesn't make a lot of sense to consider batches larger than half the entire population.  This brings the total calculation down to about a week per `p_value`.  So the simplest parallelization (assuming you have at least 4 cores to run on), is to run each of your `p_value`s as a separate run; no multiprocessing code required.  Then you can get your complete simulated answer in a week.

If you do have a lot more cores at your disposal, then setting up a `multiprocessing.Pool` to run a large number of `simulate_batch_testing` calls in parallel will get your answer even faster.